# Setting cabal configuration options in a stack project

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

In my stack project I have a `myproject.cabal` file.  I would like to try the cabal option `--disable-library-profiling` documented here:

https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html

However, I've been unable to figure out where that option must be used: wherever I put it, subsequent stack runs exit with failure (complaining in one way or another about the option).

My higher-level goal is to see if this speeds up ghc compilation for my project, but that's really secondary as far as this question goes: I'd really just like to know how these configuration options work (in the context of stack projects).

I'm using ghc 6.7.  In particular, if I use `cabal configure`, the option ends up configured in `ghc-options` in my `myproject.cabal` file, but GHC then complains:

```
ghc: unrecognised flag: --disable-library-profiling
```

I'm already using other `ghc-options` without running into similar trouble -- stack completes successfully in this case:

```
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -O0 -j +RTS -A128m -n2m -RTS
```

but not in this case:

```
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -O0 -j +RTS -A128m -n2m -RTS --disable-library-profiling
```

Comment: Are you aware the library profiling is already disabled by default? `--disable-library-profiling` is a `cabal` flag, not a `ghc` flag.

Comment: I was unsure about that, thanks (but I'd still like to know how to set cabal options).  Re that flag being for cabal: that's why I guessed that `cabal configure` would not put the flag where in fact it does, in `ghc-options`.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `ghc 6.7` ? IIRC, there was no 6.7 release.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure of that, no: I just know I'm using `resolver: lts-6.7` in my `stack.yaml`, which I believe refers to: https://github.com/fpco/lts-haskell

Answer (score 1):

The stack equivalent of `--disable-library-profiling` is:

```
$ stack build --no-library-profiling
```